# Join lines based on a starting value using UNIX commands

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Here I am again, with another UNIX requirement (as my knowledge in UNIX is limited to basic commands).

I have a file that looks like this (and has about 30 million lines)

```
123456789012,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
123456789012,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
123456789012,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
456789012345,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
```

The final output should be like this (without the first value repeating in the joined portions)

```
123456789012,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
456789012345,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
```

However, if the above output is a bit complicated, an output like below is also fine. Because I can load the file into Oracle11g and get rid of the redundant columns.

```
123456789012,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,123456789012,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,123456789012,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,234567890123,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,345678901234,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,345678901234,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
456789012345,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,567890123456,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
```

Comment: Is the input file sorted on the first column?

Comment: no its not. but if there are duplicate first values, they appear one after the other and not at random points in the file.

Comment: python would give you a more clear and future-proof script than bash commands...

Comment: @beroe: Python is a `bash` command, or at least a command runnable from `bash`, like `awk` and `sed` and `grep` and `perl` are commands runnable from `bash`.

Comment: I'm running these UNIX commands via Cygwin for Windows, don't think it supports Python. But I could try getting the Python package installed to execute Python code.

Comment: @Joshua1729 Python will run under Cygwin. I just thought from your introductory remarks that it might benefit you in the long-run to have some utility Python scripts (in which this kind of operation is trivial) rather than a contorted `awk`...

Comment: @beroe Oh! I see! Like I said, UNIX newb :D! This is a one time exercise. I need to ultimately do a bunch of JOINS on the first value. I could load the whole thing into Oracle, but then due to duplicate first values, I'd end up getting a Cartesian product when I attempt joining tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` is sufficient; it is a control-break report of sorts.  Since the lines with the same key are grouped together — a very important point — it is fairly simple.

```
awk -F, '{   if ($1 != saved)
             {
                 if (saved != 0) print saved "," list
                 saved = $1
                 list = ""
             }
             pad = ""
             for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { list = list pad $i; pad = "," }
         }
         END { if (saved != 0) print saved, list }'
```

You can feed the data as standard input or list the files to be processed after the final single quote.

Sample output:

```
123456789012,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
456789012345,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456 PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
```

The code uses `saved` to keep a track of the key column value that it is accumulating.  When the key column changes, print out the saved values (if there are any) and reset for the new set of lines.  At the end, print out the saved values (if there are any).  The code deals with an empty file gracefully, therefore.

---

#### Perl options

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $saved = "";
my $list;
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my($key,$value) = ($_ =~ m/^([^,]+)(,.*)/);
    if ($key ne $saved)
    {
        print "$saved$list\n" if $saved;
        $saved = $key;
        $list = "";
    }
    $list .= $value;
}
print "$saved$list\n" if $saved;
```

Or, if you really want to, you can saved writing the loop (and using strict and warnings) with:

```
perl -n -e 'chomp;
($key,$value) = ($_ =~ m/^([^,]+)(,.*)/);
if ($key ne $saved)
{
    print "$saved$list\n" if $saved;
    $saved = $key;
    $list = "";
}
$list .= $value;
} END {
print "$saved$list\n" if $saved;'
```

That could be squished down to a single (rather long) line.  The `} END {` is a piece of Perl weirdness; the `-n` option creates a loop `while (<>) { … }` and interpolates the script in the `-e` argument into it, so the `}` in `} END {` terminates that loop and then creates an `END` block which is ended by the `}` that Perl provided.  Yes, documented and supported; yes, extremely weird (so I wouldn't do it; I'd use the Perl script shown first).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!Thats exactly how the rows appear. Trying this now, will keep you posted!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: you lost "PDPCH=2-0," somewhere.

Comment: Ah — bug; `for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)` (with `<=` instead of `<`).  Counting from 1 (well, 2 in this case) to NF instead of 0 to NF-1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The awk script works perfectly, thank you. Will try out the perl in a while!

Comment: +1 for several options. Though `} END {` is usually just written as [`}{`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting) or you can write it just like `awk`'s `END` block.

Comment: In addition to what @jaypal has said, the Perl "one-liner" can be shortened by using the `-l` option, removing the `chomp` and the newlines from the print statements.

Comment: Both @jaypal and TomFrench make valid points.  I'll defend myself (half-heartedly) with TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It — which is Perl's motto.  _I observe that the SO rule that denies you the right to write @ in front of two names in a single comment (meaning that references can't be symmetric) is ridiculous.  I know that only the first mentioned will get notified; that's OK.  I want the cleanliness of referring to both commentators using the same notation — and the @ notation to notify one of them.  The rule also makes discussing Perl arrays in comments hard._

Comment: Since it is your answer, this comment will automatically get to you, so I will use this to invite @TomFenech. `;)` Oh yea and totally agree comments are not really `perl` friendly. `:P`.

Comment: @jaypal thanks for notifying me but it looks like the original comment was intended for Tom _French_, whoever that is :)

Comment: Oh, sorry @TomFenech; I mistranscribed your name — in my exasperation at SO.

Comment: No problem, it's not the first time and I daresay it won't be the last. Of course, the autocomplete feature would've prevented it from happening at all!

Answer (score 2):

This awk script does what you want:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR == 1 { a[++n] = $1 }
a[1] != $1 { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS); n = 1 }
{ a[1] = $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) a[++n] = $i }
END { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS) }
```

It stores all of the fields with the same first column in an array. When the first column differs, it prints out all of the elements of the array. Use it like `awk -f join.awk file`.

Output:

```
123456789012,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
234567890123,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
345678901234,PID=1,AID=2,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
456789012345,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
567890123456,PID=2,AID=1,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0,PID=3,AID=8,EQOSID=1,PDPTY=IPV4,PDPCH=2-0
```

Comment: How well does it work if handed an empty input (`/dev/null` or `NUL:`)?

Comment: It prints a single blank line but why would you want to do that?!

Comment: I wouldn't; it would be neater if it printed nothing when it got no input.  Empty files can be generated by accident.

Comment: Edited to implement your feature request :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Python options, if you decide to go that route... First will work for multiple input files and non-sequential identical indices. Second doesn't read the whole file into memory.

(Note, I know it is not convention, but I intentionally use UpperCase for variables to make it clear what is a user-defined variable and what is a special python word.)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
concatenate comma-separated values based on first value

Usage: 
   catfile.py *.txt > output.dat

"""
import sys

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    sys.stderr.write(__doc__)
else:
    FileList = sys.argv[1:]
    IndexList = []
    OutDict = {}
    for FileName in FileList:
        with open(FileName,'rU') as FStream:
            for Line in FStream:
                if Line:
                    Ind,TheRest = Line.rstrip().split(",",1)
                    if Ind not in IndexList:
                        IndexList.append(Ind)
                    OutDict[Ind] = OutDict.get(Ind,"") + "," + TheRest

    for Ind in IndexList:
        print Ind + OutDict[Ind]
```

Here is a different version which doesn't load the whole file into memory, but requires that the identical Indices all occur in order, and it only runs on one file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
concatenate comma-separated values based on first value

Usage: 
   catfile.py *.txt > output.dat

"""
import sys

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    sys.stderr.write(__doc__)
else:
    FileName = sys.argv[1]
    OutString = ''
    PrevInd = ''
    FirstLine = True
    with open(FileName,'rU') as FStream:
        for Line in FStream:
            if "," in Line:
                Ind,TheRest = Line.rstrip().split(",",1)
                if Ind != PrevInd:
                    if not FirstLine:
                        print PrevInd+OutString
                    PrevInd = Ind
                    OutString = TheRest
                    FirstLine = False
                else:
                    OutString += ","+TheRest
        print Ind + OutString
```

More generally, you can run these with by saving them as say `catfile.py` and then doing `python catfile.py inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`. Or for longer term solutions, make a `scripts` directory, add it to your `$PATH`, make them executable with `chmod u+x catfile.py` and then you can just type the name of the script from any directory. But that is another topic that you would want to research.

Comment: This reads the whole file into memory, which probably doesn't matter if it is only 1 GiB or less, but starts to matter if the file gets much bigger than that.

Comment: Files are 3-6 GB in size... but the system has 32 GB of RAM. So I think it can handle it. Although I have no idea how to execute the above code!!

Comment: Save it in `catfile.py`.  Run it as `python catfile.py data-file`

Answer (score 0):

A way without array:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," ; ORS = "" }
{
    if (lid == $1) { $1 = "" ; print $0 }
    else { print sep $0 ; lid = $1 ; sep = "\n" }
}
END { if (NR) print }
```

Note: if you don't need a newline at the end, remove the END block.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sort file | sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^(([^,]*),.*)\n\2/\1/;ta;P;D'
```

Sort the file (if need be) and then delete newline and key where duplicates appear.